# convert vim regex to python for re.sub

Tags: python, regex, vim

I have a working regex under vim: `/^ \{-}\a.*$\n`

I implement a global search and replace as    `:%s/^ \{-}\a.*$\n//`
This works great -- removes all lines that start with any number of spaces (matched non-greedily), followed by a letter and anything else to the end of the line including the newline.

I cannot (to save my soul) figure out the analogous regex in Python. Here's what make sense to me:

```
x = re.sub("^ *?\a.$\n","",y)
```

But this doesn't do anything.

Many thanks for your sagacious replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\a` means the bell character (0x07) in Python, and `$\n` is a redundant bad idea, so:

```
x = re.sub(r"^ *[A-Za-z].*\n","",y)
```

Also, there's no reason to write `' *?'` instead of `' *'` here, as it's always going to be followed by a non-space if it's matching.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match any number of whitespace, you can also use the `\s` sequence.

Any letter will be matched by the `[a-zA-Z]` character class. You also don't need to use the `$` and the `\n`, either will do.

Suggest the following:

```
x = re.sub(r"^\s*[a-zA-Z].*(\r|\n)","",y)
```

If you want at least one whitespace, use `\s+` instead of `\s*`